# Accessing struct elements based on user input on scanf

Tags: c, input, struct

I have to access different elements from struct based on what user inputs on scanf.

For example, if a user inputs "grade", I need to pass it on a function, and return the values of struct.grade, but then with the same function, I need to be able to do the same thing with different inputs such as struct.name or struct.id for example.

How can I use the user input from scanf("%s") to the function?

I tried using switch case in my main, to turn different input into different numbers. Grade = 1, name = 2, etc. Then passing it to the functions, with idea of indexing the struct. But then I can't figure out how to access struct elements from given numbers. I tried searching for struct indexing but didn't find anything.

Any other method would be fine though.

Brief code example below

```c
struct class{
    char name[50];
    int score;
    char grade[2];
}data[100];

void function(struct, input){}
// expected function workflow:
// takes the input from the argument,
// example function(data, "grade")
// count unique grades (I have this algorithm already)
// but then I can use the same code for another input such as name.
// the question is how to make my functiom able to access data.grade in this call,
// and the same function able to access data.name in other function call with function(data, "name") as its input?


int main(){
char input[10];
scanf("%s", input); getchar();
// a function that takes input as parameter
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If all the fields are the same type, you can use a callback function to extract the field. But it seems that the fields are different types (grades are numeric but names are text), in which case a single function cannot handle both fields.

Comment: Why the complexity of trying to write a function... Just use the struct member directly, be that `int`, `double`, `char*` or whatever... Perhaps your function could return an integer value corresponding to the user's desire and a `switch()` to produce the response.

Comment: `char grade[2];` is questionable. As a string, this will only ever be able to hold one character, so it might be better as just a `char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) to compare the user's input against certain strings, and branch based on the results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char input[128];

    printf("Enter a command: ");

    if (!fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin))
        return 1;

    input[strcspn(input, "\r\n")] = 0;

    struct {
        char name[64];
        int score;
        char grade;
    } student = {
        "Dru", 42, 'B'
    };

    if (0 == strcmp(input, "name"))
        printf("%s\n", student.name);
    else if (0 == strcmp(input, "score"))
        printf("%d\n", student.score);
    else if (0 == strcmp(input, "grade"))
        printf("%c\n", student.grade);
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Command <%s> not recognized.\n", input);
}
```

```
Enter a command: score
42
```

Comment: I figured earlier that this might be the solution as well, but then if I have like a 30-line code for each element, I have to do 30*elements for it to run correctly, which is ridiculously long. That was why I tried looking for other solutions, but looks like there's none. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. What do you mean by *"each element"*? Do you mean struct *member*?

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. For example, say that I need to puts() 50 times for 5 struct members, I need to have 5*50 lines of puts, right?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you actually want to *do* with each member of the structure. Structure members of the same type (or those easily converted to a common type) could be passed to the same function, given you want to perform the same action(s) for each. You might want to update your question with a more complete [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This may be somewhat of an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). If you can clarify your goals, I (or someone else) might be able to give a more accurate answer.

Comment: Honestly I don't know how to explain better, but I did the 'manual' way of the long if elses and it works. I'll just close it here. Thank you.